# NStableView does not react to notification @"NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification" call on Ventura

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsviewcontroller

I used an Objective-C method to get the managedObjects on Xcode 9.2.
Today I have a new iMac with Xcode 14.3 and the method is not called.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
  _center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  [_center addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(selectionDidchange:)
            name:@"NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification"
            object:nil];
  NSLog(@"arraController %@",_vrController); // o.k
  NSLog(@"tableView %@",_vrTableView); // o.k
  NSLog(@"center %@",_center); // o.k
}
```

```
-(void)selectionDidchange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  if((_vrController != nil) && (_vrTableView != nil))
  {
      selected = [_vrController selectedObjects];
      arranged = [_vrController arrangedObjects];
      _currentObject = [selected objectAtIndex:0];
      if(_currentObject != nil)
        {
          NSData * data;
          NSError * error;
          _vrRoot = [NSMutableDictionary new];
          
          data =[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_vrRoot
                  requiringSecureCoding:YES error:&error];
          [_currentObject setValue:data forKey:@"kVrRoot"];
        }
    }
```

In the Developer Documentation I read: NSTableView (macOS 10.0+).
I assume the doc is not up to date.

I expect the newest documentation (if there is one).

Comment: When you see `NSTableView (macOS 10.0+)`, that means that the `NSTableView` class can be used starting with macOS 10.0 and later. That is up-to-date.

Comment: Did you change anything? You should use `NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` instead of `@"NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification"` but it should work. What is the class of `self`?

Comment: @willeke self AppDelegate * 0x6000004d4f60 0x00006000004d4f60 Edit:i use XIP, not NSViewController.